# Does Spotify offer a radio-type service that allows me to fine tune the selection?

Tags: music, spotify

I'm looking at various music services. What I want is something similar to Pandora's radio based on artist followed by fine-tuning with thumbs up/down combined with a much larger catalog and the ability to also do on-demand playing of tracks and albums.

I was hoping Spotify might work, but it's unclear how their radio feature works, can I seed it with an track or just an artist? Can I later fine-tune the selection by rating the currently playing track up or down?

Comment: For those who are voting to close... I specifically asked on the SU moderators chat channel and one person there told me this was ok before I posted.

Comment: That was my bad. I thought you were asking about a feature already in the Spotify application. Also, I am not a moderator. I'm sorry for the confusion. :(

Comment: That's cool. If the question should be moved, I'm happy with that. I just don't know which SE site it should go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. They are planning on releasing one but they do not currently.

http://www.spotify.com/us/blog/archives/2011/12/09/discover-the-new-spotify-radio/

UPDATE:

Apparently it is already live, actually, in the preview version of the Spotify app. Google search shows it's being panned in reviews: https://www.google.com/search?q=spotify+radio+service

Comment: Do you have references for these plans, like a roadmap?

Comment: http://www.spotify.com/us/blog/archives/2011/12/09/discover-the-new-spotify-radio/

Comment: Does it allow fine-tuning?

Comment: I don't know...